# jQuery script not running until page is live edited

Tags: jquery, edit, live

I currently have the following simple jQuery function, simply works to fade in and out 4 divs on mouse hover:

```
$('#jig1').mouseover(function(){    
    $('#jig2, #jig3, #jig4').fadeTo(2000, 0.15, function(){});
    $('#jig1').fadeTo(2000, 1, function() {});
});

$('#jig2').mouseover(function(){    
    $('#jig1, #jig3, #jig4').fadeTo(2000, 0.15, function(){});
    $('#jig2').fadeTo(2000, 1, function() {});
});

$('#jig3').mouseover(function(){    
    $('#jig1, #jig2, #jig4').fadeTo(2000, 0.15, function(){});
    $('#jig3').fadeTo(2000, 1, function() {});
});

$('#jig4').mouseover(function(){    
    $('#jig1, #jig2, #jig3').fadeTo(2000, 0.15, function(){});
    $('#jig4').fadeTo(2000, 1, function() {});
});
```

This script does work to do exactly what I intended it to, however there is a big issue somewhere, since the script only works after I have loaded a page, and live edited the script with a dev. tool such as Firebug. And by live edited, I mean added in any character and then removed it, otherwise rendering it identical to before the edit, yet somehow in doing so it then runs.

Any idea why it's doing this? I'm totally stumped.

Comment: Are you waiting for DOM ready?

Comment: I had but placed the script after the call rather than inside it, working now, thanks for the brain jog!